# VBA Paste function throwing error after VBA Clear function

Tags: vba, excel

I have an advanced filter that is being used to sort a large data set.

The filter is dropping the filtered data into a separate sheet.

I have a VBA Macro that allows me to highlight the portions of the filter that I want to use and paste it into a range adjacent to the filter table.

Currently I am using very simple VBA. 
The copy of the active selection and paste into the next open row after a specified Cell. The cell is a row of headers that corresponds to the headers of the table  that the copy selection is being made from.

```
 Sub CopyPaste()
      Selection.Copy
      ActiveSheet.Range("J6").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
 End Sub
```

The clear is very simple.

```
Sub ClearTable()

    ActiveSheet.Range("J7:O100").Clear

End Sub
```

After the clear is run, I receive an error.

Get Run Time error '1004, Application-defined or object defined error.

EDIT: Clarification. .clear and .clearcontents both lead to the errored state If I attempt to paste after I clear the range.

Comment: What do you expect `.clear` to do? I think you mean `.clearcontents`?

Comment: The problem isn't with the clear. Clear works fine. After the clear, I am getting an error with the paste.

Edit: Tried Clearcontents. Error Still shows when I attempt to paste again.

Comment: With J7:O100 cleared, select J6 and tap [ctrl]+[down arrow]. Try and go one more row further down. That is where you are trying to paste and if you follow my directions the problem should be perfectly obvious.

Comment: Use `Selection.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)` ; this looks from the bottom up and selects 1 row down not from the top down (which seems to be J1048576 and cannot be moved down a row let alone having room for the paste).

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I can see what Jeeped was saying now, and thank for for the Destination:= code. I hadn't run across this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With J7:O100 cleared, select J6 and tap [ctrl]+[down arrow]. Try and go one more row further down. That is where you are trying to paste and if you follow my directions the problem should be perfectly obvious.

Use,

```
Selection.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This looks from the bottom up and selects 1 row down not from the top down (which seems to be J1048576 and cannot be moved down a row let alone having room for the paste).